# Extract hyperlinks from PDF file

Tags: java, apache-poi, pdfbox

I am trying to extract hyperlinks and its corresponding URL by hovering on it from PDF file and trying to print it.

I tried to use Apache PDFBox library in my code but getting no results. Can anyone help me through this?

Code which i am trying:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fis);
        List<PDPage> pages = (List<PDPage>) document.getPages();
        for (PDPage page : pages) {
            List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
            for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) {
                if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                    PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annotation;
                    PDActionURI action = (PDActionURI) link.getAction();
                    if (action != null) {
                        String url = action.getURI();
                        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please link to your PDF so we can have a look. Your code looks ok IMHO. (Unrelated: you'll get more performance with `PDDocument.load(new File(filepath))` than by using a stream)

Comment: Try looking at [How to extract hyperlink information PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587567/how-to-extract-hyperlink-information-pdfbox).

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error in my console screen:

Usage: AddDimensionedImage imageFile outputFile

Comment: I am using normal sample pdf doc with a link to google and yahoo site.

Comment: Your code does not have "AddDimensionedImage" in it.

Comment: So what we need to do in this case?

Comment: 1) Share your document, 2) Post the relevant code. You claim that you're getting the error "AddDimensionedImage imageFile outputFile" but your code does no such thing.